# Mount accidentally disconected cdrom

Tags: mount, dvd, drive, cd

I had a DVD drive and a external hard drive connected to my PC and I've disconnected them accidentally.
Now I've already spent hours trying to access them, mount, umount and can't figure how to connect the devices again.
Can't believe how such a simple thing can be such a headache in linux
I can see the directory where the devices were mounted previously, but a there is nothing inside them.
Can anyone help me out? I'm new to Linux and I'm finding this very frustrating at the moment.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reboot the machine and check once

if its not solved

Check mount /dev/sr0 /media

Did your External Drive was in ext4 file system or its a NTFS ?

Comment: Hard drive in NTFS. When trying to mount /dev/sr0 I get the error wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sr0

Comment: After a few restarts it's working again. I haven't tried the Hard Drive yet but it is not important for now. I can ftp instead. Tks for replying